# Slack interactive message getting invalid_payload for response_url sent back

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack, slack-api

I've been doing some work with the Slack API and with their
[interactive messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9MUY.png)

I post a message with the interactive message attachment here:

```
export const postMessage = (msg, channel) => {
    request({
      method: 'POST',
      uri: 'https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage',
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.SLACKTOKEN}`,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        token: process.env.SLACKTOKEN,
        attachments: [
          {
              "text": "",
              "fallback": "If you could read this message, you'd be choosing something fun to do right now.",
              "color": "#3AA3E3",
              "attachment_type": "default",
              "callback_id": "command_selection",
              "actions": [
                  {
                      "name": "command_list",
                      "text": "Choose a command",
                      "type": "select",
                      "options": [
                          {
                              "text": "Register Team",
                              "value": "registerTeam"
                          },
                          {
                              "text": "Edit Team",
                              "value": "editTeam"
                          },
                          {
                              "text": "Get By Url",
                              "value": "getByUrl"
                          },
                          {
                              "text": "Report Issue",
                              "value": "reportIssue"
                          },
                          {
                              "text": "Find Team",
                              "value": "findTeam"
                          },
                          {
                              "text": "List Teams",
                              "value": "listTeams"
                          }
                      ]
                  }
              ]
          }
      ],
        text: msg,
        channel,
        as_user: true,
      })
    }, (err, res, body) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log('error posting msg: ', err);
      } else {
        console.log('post message to channel: ', body);
      }
    })
  }
```

Slack then sends a POST request to this [URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VN9mr.png) with a response_url parameter in their payload. This is where I'm getting the payload from in my code:

```
    api.post('/interactivity', (req, res) => {
        const { body } = req;
        const { payload } = body;
        const parsedPayload = JSON.parse(payload)
        res.send(parsedPayload.response_url)
        var message = {
            "text": payload.user.name+" clicked: "+payload.actions[0].name,
            "replace_original": false,
        }
        util.sendMessageToSlackResponseURL(parsedPayload.response_url, message)
    })
```

```
  export const sendMessageToSlackResponseURL = (responseURL, JSONmessage) => {
    var postOptions = {
        uri: responseURL,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        json: JSONmessage
    }
    request(postOptions, (error, res, body) => {
        if (error){
            console.log(error)
        } else {
          console.log('post message to channel: ', body);
        }
    })
}
```

For some reason though, the response_url is giving an invalid_payload error when I click on the link and I can't figure out if its the payload I'm sending in the original message I posted or something's up with the POST request that Slack sent

Comment: Tried to contact Slack via `/feedback` ?

Comment: Can you please share this `sendMessageToSlackResponseURL()` utility method?

Comment: @HenonoaH Just edited my question with it

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with utility method on line `json: JSONmessage` which should be `body: JSONmessage`

Updated code,

```js
  export const sendMessageToSlackResponseURL = (responseURL, JSONmessage) => {
    var postOptions = {
        uri: responseURL,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSONmessage
    }
    request(postOptions, (error, res, body) => {
        if (error){
            console.log(error)
        } else {
          console.log('post message to channel: ', body);
        }
    })
}
```

Hope this works!